# The method getBinaryPath() is undefined for the type WebDriverManager error shows in eclipse while i am trying to run appium automation project

Tags: java, eclipse, appium, webdrivermanager-java

I am trying to run a mini appium project, I have the emulator and an appium server running and here's my code, it says that `.getBinaryPath() is undefined for type WebDriverManager "caps.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", WebDriverManager.chromedriver().getBinaryPath());"`

```
package appiumBasics;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

@Test
public class RubWebApplicationAndroidEmulator {

    public void OpenWebApplication() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "HaidyEmulator");
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    caps.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", WebDriverManager.chromedriver().getBinaryPath());
        
    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),caps);
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because if you actually go to the repository and open the problematic class, you find there is no such method defined for `WebDriverManager`:

https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/WebDriverManager.java

Presumably this was changed at some point. Possibly you need `WebDriverManager#getDownloadedDriverPath()`:

```
@Test
public class RubWebApplicationAndroidEmulator {

    public void OpenWebApplication() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "HaidyEmulator");
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    caps.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", WebDriverManager.chromedriver().getDownloadedDriverPath());
        
    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),caps);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I was able to find the commit where this change occurred and it seems `getDownloadedDriverPath()` is the right guess: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/commit/411878405c52078a44df1ecd3903c7de8be894fd